# Android multiple Adviews in a layout

Tags: java, android, adview

I have to make of two AdViews in a layout. Both top and Bottom of a layout. I have done for one(the top). Now i want to make it one more AdView in the bottom of the layout. How to achieve it? Thanks in advance. My Code for top AdView in layout as follows.

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "unused" })
public class BannerEssentials extends Activity{
WebView webview;
static String MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID="google";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

// BANNER 1

// Lookup R.layout.main
AbsoluteLayout layout = (AbsoluteLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

// Create the adView
// Please replace MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID with your AdMob Publisher ID
AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, MY_BANNER_UNIT_ID);

// Add the adView to it
layout.addView(adView);

// Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
request.setTesting(true);

adView.loadAd(request)
```

Comment: Just as an aside, watch out for AbsoluteLayout.  It's deprecated for a reason - it's super bad.

Answer (score 0):

Add another item to the linearlayout with width="fill_parent" and height="0dip". Then set the weight="1". This should have the effect of pushing whatever is below down. Then duplicate the code above to add in the new advertisement.

You should look into defining your views in XML, advertisements can also be inserted directly through XML or you could also [define your own custom view](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)